# Cocos2d 3.2.1 can run in debug mode not release mode on Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I downloaded the cocos2d 3.2.1.zip and run it on xcode 6.
Debug mode is fine but release mode is not ok at all.
I am getting the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_uncompress", referenced from:
      _ccInflateCCZFile in libcocos2d.a(ZipUtils.o)
  "_gzopen", referenced from:
      _ccInflateGZipFile in libcocos2d.a(ZipUtils.o)
  "_gzread", referenced from:
      _ccInflateGZipFile in libcocos2d.a(ZipUtils.o)
  "_gzclose", referenced from:
      _ccInflateGZipFile in libcocos2d.a(ZipUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am sure it's about the project settings. Does any one know how to solve it?

Comment: I am also getting the following:Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_uncompress", referenced from:
      _ccInflateCCZFile in libcocos2d.a(ZipUtils.o)
  "_gzopen", referenced from:
      _ccInflateGZipFile in libcocos2d.a(ZipUtils.o)
  "_gzread", referenced from:
      _ccInflateGZipFile in libcocos2d.a(ZipUtils.o)
  "_gzclose", referenced from:
      _ccInflateGZipFile in libcocos2d.a(ZipUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was trying to compile one of my old projects for 64 bits in new xcode. The solution was to go to the build phases -> link binary with libraries -> add libz.1.dylib.